# How to tell PhpStorm to ignore file separators when comparing files?

Tags: php, synchronization, phpstorm

I searched far and wide and I'm not even sure it is possible, but please let me know if you know anything that might be useful.

I use PhpStorm 9.0 to edit my .php files. I sometimes use multiple servers and multiple local computers to work on one project, which calls for a lot of synchronizing of files.

PhpStorm's built-in synchronization function works pretty well, however I repeatedly face the problem with **line separators.**

For example out of 50 files there are 3 which are changed, but since the server changes line separators on it's own, PhpStorm treats all those files as changed, which means I can't review just the 3 files, I have to browse through all 50 to check which are changed.

Anybody here has been successful with changing this behavior to ignore line separators?

Comment: Fix the problem at source. Don't let servers to change your files.

Comment: 1) You can apply some policy to use Linux endings only -- works fine for PHP/HTML/CSS/JS files -- PHP and browsers execute such files just fine on Windows (so no reason to use OS specific endings). BTW -- it's recommended by one of the PSR for PHP anyway; 2) You can configure your git (or whatever your VCS is) to not to convert line endings automatically; 3) The same should be applied to the FTP server

Comment: In any case: As far as I'm aware it's not currently possible to do that in current PhpStorm versions: e.g. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-101502 and related; https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-139732

Comment: I Also suggest to **try latest 2016.3** version -- there might be some other improvements made in this or related area -- different versions can be run in parallel (just backup project settings (`.idea` subfolder) as v9 is quite old so settings may be lost when opening this project again in older IDE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well .. technically line endings are kind of ignored (when comparing content by lines) .. but files with the difference in line endings only are still listed as being different in the actual file list:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-101502
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-139732

Watch those tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

Comment: so it seems this is not possible... it's sad that such an awesome tool as phpstorm doesn't have any button like "ignore different file endings" in synchronization window... :/